# Cant autowire an interface

Tags: java, spring

I was following Spring Security tutorial at youtube and got stuck with autowiring simple interface at one of the services.

Service:

```
@Service
public class ApplicationUserService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final ApplicationUserDAO applicationUserDAO;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationUserService(ApplicationUserDAO applicationUserDAO) {
        this.applicationUserDAO = applicationUserDAO;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        return applicationUserDAO.selectApplicationUserByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(String.format("Username %s not found.", username)));
    }
}
```

ApplicationUserDAO:

```
import java.util.Optional;


public interface ApplicationUserDAO {

    Optional<ApplicationUser> selectApplicationUserByUsername(String userName);
}
```

Service constructor parameter applicationUserDAO is highlighted by Idea with error "Could not autowire. No beans of 'ApplicationUserDAO' type found. "

I tried to annotate DAO with @Component and Idea calmed down, but i still got "Parameter 0 of constructor in com.example.demo.auth.ApplicationUserService required a bean of type 'com.example.demo.auth.ApplicationUserDAO' that could not be found." when i tried to launch the application.

Comment: You need to provide an implementation for this interface (i.e. a class that `implements ApplicationUserDAO`). An interface is just the declaration of (abstract) methods without implementation.

Comment: An instance is Autowired. Have you created an instance of this interface and placed it in the spring context?

Comment: @Turing85 ill try this option, thank you. Problem is that tutor did it without any implementations. May it be preconfigured somehow? I'm not sure if i am allowed to post youtube links here to show what i am talking about)

Comment: @Polos I doubt that. There are a few instances (e.g. with `JpaRepository` and `CrudRepository`) where Spring can generate implementations based on the method names. But this only works for particular interfaces with a very specific scope.

Comment: I think you are missing something from that tutorial. Shouldn't `ApplicationUserDAO` extend some kind of a repository?

Comment: @ErvinSzilagyi nope it is not. I watched tutorial further and saw that tutor creates a new class that implements this interface. I did the same and it worked. So problem was that his IDE didn't highlight the injection problem before providing an implementation for this interface and mine did ) Extending it with repository is also a solution, so thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a bean that implemented by ApplicationUserDAO.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationUserDAOImpl implements ApplicationUserDAO {
    @Override 
    Optional<ApplicationUser> selectApplicationUserByUsername(String userName) {
         return null;
    }
}
```